# glDrawElements has stopped working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, graphics, vertex

I had `glDrawElements` working consistently, initially with a simple box and then with more complex shapes made up of a large amount of vertices. Then it simply stopped drawing the mesh. I have taken the code back to it's most basic, just drawing 2 triangles to make a 2D square. This also no longer works.

```
void createMesh(void) {
    float vertices[12];
    vertices[0] = -0.5; vertices[1] = -0.5; vertices[2] = 0.0; // Bottom left corner
    vertices[3] = -0.5; vertices[4] = 0.5; vertices[5] = 0.0; // Top left corner
    vertices[6] = 0.5; vertices[7] = 0.5; vertices[8] = 0.0; // Top Right corner
    vertices[9] = 0.5; vertices[10] = -0.5; vertices[11] = 0.0; // Bottom right corner

    short indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);        // Enable Vertex Arrays

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices); // Set The Vertex Pointer To Our Vertex Data

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6 , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices); 

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

The more advanced code that used to work is shown below:

```
void createMesh(void) {
float vertices[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];// Amount of vertices
    //build the array of vertices from a matrix of data
    int currentVertex = -1;
    std::vector <std::vector<double>> currentPointCloudMatrix = distanceCalculator.getPointCloudMatrix();
    double plotY = 0;
    double plotX = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < currentPointCloudMatrix.size(); j++){
        std::vector <double> singleDistancesVector = currentPointCloudMatrix.at(j); 
        for (int i = 0; i < singleDistancesVector.size(); i++){
            if (singleDistancesVector.at(i) != 0){
                vertices[++currentVertex] = plotX;
                vertices[++currentVertex] = plotY;
                vertices[++currentVertex] = singleDistancesVector.at(i);
            }
            plotX += 0.1;
        }
        plotX = 0;
        plotY += 0.2; //increment y by 0.02     
    }

    //Creating the array of indices, 480 is the amount of columns
    int i = 0;
    short indices2[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];
    for (int row = 0; row<amountOfHorizontalScans - 1; row++) {
        if ((row & 1) == 0) { // even rows
            for (int col = 0; col<480; col++) {
                indices2[i++] = col + row * 480;
                indices2[i++] = col + (row + 1) * 480;
            }
        }
        else { // odd rows
            for (int col = 480 - 1; col>0; col--) {
                indices2[i++] = col + (row + 1) * 480;
                indices2[i++] = col - 1 + +row * 480;
            }
        }
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);        // Enable Vertex Arrays

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices); // Set The Vertex Pointer To Our Vertex Data

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, (amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices2);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

I am at a complete loss as to why it has stopped working as it was working perfectly for a good number of runs, then just completely stopped. I have debugged through and all the code is being reached, also the vertices and indices are populated with data. What could cause this to stop working?

EDIT:
So I am really quite confused now. I came back to this issue this morning, and everything worked fine again, as in the meshes would draw with no issues. After doing some tests and running the program a number of times it has simply stopped drawing meshes again!

Could this be something memory related? I am not 100% sure on how glDrawElements stores the data passed to it, so could it be that I have to clear something somewhere that I keep filling up with data?

Comment: "has stopped working" is a bit vague. What happens when you run the code, how does it differ from what you are expecting? Are there any compile-time / run-time errors?

Comment: Ah my bad, it used to create a visible mesh for the vertices that I had, whether that was the simple square or a large set of vertices from a matrix. Then it simply stopped creating the mesh, no errors to be seen, it just no longer draws anything.

Comment: Try calling `glGetError()` if you have not already done so. What type/version of context are you creating?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot allocate dynamically arrays in stack:

```
short indices2[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];
```

In code:

```
short indices2[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];
for (int row = 0; row<amountOfHorizontalScans - 1; row++) {
    if ((row & 1) == 0) { // even rows
        for (int col = 0; col<480; col++) {
            indices2[i++] = col + row * 480;
            indices2[i++] = col + (row + 1) * 480;
        }
    }
    else { // odd rows
        for (int col = 480 - 1; col>0; col--) {
            indices2[i++] = col + (row + 1) * 480;
            indices2[i++] = col - 1 + +row * 480;
        }
    }
}
```

Must be

```
short* indices2 = new short[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];
```

than free allocated memory

```
delete [] indices2;
```

Triangle strip is pretty tricky mode did you try to work directly with `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Comment: Somehow missed that line in my question, updated the code in the top. But it's definitely there in original code. Even if that was the issue, the first 2D square should work. To clarify, this is not a fix.

Comment: is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Surely the initial 2D square should work fine though, as it not affected by this?

Comment: @Calco Yes it works but what about `short indices2[(amountOfHorizontalScans * 480 * 3)];` did you declare `amountOfHorizontalScans` as constant?

Comment: amountOfHorizontalScans is a constant. I am inclined to believe it is something memory related, as it works again after turning my PC off and on again! Creating the pointer and calling delete as above now causes an 'Access Violation' at runtime when calling glDrawElements.

Comment: @Calco 'Access Violation' can also be caused by invalid index specification means out of array border read. So check your index calculation the issue may lay in that place.